# Custom Tab on TOOLS region only appears when there is an object on the scene

Tags: interface

I got a custom coded tab to help me with some tools. But that tab only shows itself when an object is created on the scene. Or when I select an object. Is there a way to make my custom tab on the TOOLS region stay with or without an object selected? I need it to be shown at all times.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When we define a [custom panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html#simple-object-panel), it's `bl_category` property defines the name of the tab that it will be displayed in. As long as there is an active panel for a tab it will be shown.

A panel can have a `poll()` method which should be decorated as a `@classmethod` that determines if the panel can be displayed or not, by disabling the only panel displayed in a tab, the tab will disappear. To keep a tab visible you need a panel that is always visible, possibly by removing an existing `poll()` method.